# Getting value from sub-folders to a PHP page using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, get, codeigniter-2, subdirectory

In my site I have a folder called `module`. It has two sub-folders called `module1` and `module2`. Both of them have a `index.php` page. My site is developed in CodeIgniter.

In `module1/index.php` I have the following code:

```
<?php

    $module_name = "module1";
    $module_type = "test";

?>
```

In `module2/index.php` I have the following code:

```
<?php

    $module_name = "module2";
    $module_type = "test";

?>
```

Then I have a model function `checktest()`. In that function I want to get the `module1` and `module2` name values when `$module_type = test`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question, but instead of a module folder you should make a controller named Module and have two functions in that class named module1 and module2. Then make a third function that compares the two.